# gspread Invalid token: Stateless token expired

Tags: django, gspread

I have a web application which uses the django framework. I am using gspread to parse some data from googlesheet. On my local machine the script is running well, but once it is deployed on the web server, after about one hour I get this error:

```
    File "/home/ZhukovGreen/rmkPrjWeb/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 72, in request
        response.status_code, response.content))
    HTTPError: 401: 
    
    Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token expired
    
    
    Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token expired
    Error 401
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you authenticate gspread on your local machine and on the server?

Comment: @Burnash I am using service account and generated json file (the same for my local machine and the web server)

Comment: Do your local tests run for longer than 1 hour without error? If not, then it might be due to this error for which I gave an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880188/gspread-w-oauth2client-service-account-key

Comment: @roganjosh thanks. It was the issue. Now it works

Comment: Glad it helped you :) I'm going to flag as duplicate because `gspread` seems to have similar issues with authorisation cropping up again and again, which are somewhat hard to track down because they're unexpected. A dupe tag will make the re-direct to an answer more obvious.